# Trying to load timezone data using sql loader

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

Is there a way to load timezone data using sql loader?

Ex:Data format is `2016-04-28T08:42:24.412822Z`

In the control file I'm using the TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ

`T_DATE "TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(:T_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD HH12:MI:SS:FF TZHTZM')"`

Comment: It's throwing me an error, I guess I'm using the function correctly..

Comment: you should post the error message too.

Comment: Record 1: Rejected - Error on table TEST, column T_DATE.
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: what is the datatype of the column `t_date`?you should provide all the details in the question.

Comment: t_date column is with timestamp with time zone datatype with precision 6(default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date format model doesn't match your sample date. I doubt you really want HH12 since there is no AM/PM marker, but the problem is the fixed T from the ISO format. You can handle that [as a character literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#sthref406):

> **Punctuation and Character Literals in Datetime Format Models**
>   You can include these characters in a date format model:
>
> - Punctuation such as hyphens, slashes, commas, periods, and colons
> - Character literals, enclosed in double quotation marks

As your SQL*Loader line is already in double-quotes you need to escape that:

```
t_date "to_timestamp_tz(:T_DATE, 'yy-mm-dd\"T\"hh24:mi:ss.ff tzhtzm')"
```

Or more simply use the [built-in date/time handling](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1166) instead of an explicit [SQL operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1226), i.e.:

```
t_date timestamp with time zone 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff tzhtzm'
```